# Select all items in table A except those that are already present in table B

Tags: mysql

I wanted to list all items in `Table A` except those already present in `Table B`.

I cannot seem to find the error:

```
SELECT `topic_id`.st,`topic_title`.st 
FROM `subject_topics` st 
WHERE `topic_id`.st NOT EXIST (SELECT `topic_id`.sa 
                               FROM `subject_assign` sa 
                               WHERE `teacher_id`.sa='TEACHER')
```

I want the user to add additional topics, but of course, they should not see those items already added.

Comment: you need to do Right join

Comment: @FerrakkemBhuiyan can you demonstrate that? the solution of Aziz is already enough but if there are other ways, i would like to learn them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of table name and column name should be other way around, like this:

```
SELECT st.`topic_id`, st.`topic_title` 
FROM `subject_topics` st 
WHERE st.`topic_id` NOT IN (
  SELECT sa.`topic_id` 
  FROM `subject_assign` sa 
  WHERE sa.`teacher_id` = 'TEACHER'
)
```